# Can i use XamlServices.Save method to serialize the form child control

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization

I have tried to serialize all the child controls of the form using **XamlServices.Save** method. If i use the empty **Datagridview** which is working fine, but assign the datasource for datagridview which throws following exception,

> System.MissingMethodException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233069
>   Message=Constructor on type 'System.ComponentModel.ComponentConverter'
>   not found.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture,
>   Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>          at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture,
>   Object[] activationAttributes)
>          at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
>          at System.Xaml.Schema.SafeReflectionInvoker.CreateInstanceCritical(Type
>   type, Object[] arguments)
>          at System.Xaml.Schema.SafeReflectionInvoker.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] arguments)
>          at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlValueConverter 1.CreateInstance()
>          at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlValueConverter 1.get_ConverterInstance()
>          at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.TypeConverterExtensions.GetConverterInstance[TConverter](XamlValueConverter`1
>   converter)
>          at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.SerializerContext.TryValueSerializeToString(ValueSerializer
>   valueSerializer, TypeConverter propertyConverter, SerializerContext
>   context, Object& value)
>          at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.MemberMarkupInfo.GetPropertyValueInfoInternal(Object
>   propertyValue, ValueSerializer propertyValueSerializer, TypeConverter
>   propertyConverter, Boolean isXamlTemplate, XamlMember xamlProperty,
>   SerializerContext context)
>          at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.MemberMarkupInfo.GetPropertyValueInfo(Object
>   propertyValue, XamlMember xamlProperty, SerializerContext context)
>          at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.MemberMarkupInfo.ForReadWriteProperty(Object
>   source, XamlMember xamlProperty, SerializerContext context)
>          at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.MemberMarkupInfo.ForProperty(Object
>   source, XamlMember property, SerializerContext context)
>          at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.ObjectMarkupInfo.AddRecordMembers(Object
>   value, SerializerContext context, ParameterInfo[] methodParameters,
>   XamlType xamlType)
>          at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.ObjectMarkupInfo.AddRecordMembers(Object
>   value, SerializerContext context, TypeConverter converter)
>          at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.ObjectMarkupInfo.ForObjectInternal(Object
>   value, SerializerContext context, TypeConverter converter)
>   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.ObjectMarkupInfo.ForObject(Object value,at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

**Code**

```
private void DemonstrateTheSerializationException()
{
   // let's serialize this form to a file
   var sFullPathFileName = "test.xml";
   using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(sFullPathFileName))
   {
       XamlServices.Save(writer, this);
   }
}
```

Am i use this method for serialization or am i missed anything here?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You should not use it for WPF stuff.

"You should continue to use XamlReader.Load and XamlWriter.Save for WPF types.  WPF has a number of things in it that aren't supported directly in the lower, more general purpose, System.Xaml.dll APIs.
This is for .NET 4, not just Beta2 of .NET 4."

Use this:

```
var result=System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(this.LayoutGrid);
```

Consider cleaning your xaml graph to only include the things you really need before calling XamlServices.Save.

In my case some FrameworkElements had objects in the Tag property - and those would not serialize.

I did this to handle it:

```
public string NullOutAllTagValuesAndSerializeXaml()
{
  IterateXamlNullOutTag(this.LayoutGrid);
  return System.Xaml.XamlServices.Save(this.LayoutGrid);
}

private void IterateXamlNullOutTag(FrameworkElement fe)
{
  fe.Tag = null;
  var c=VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(fe);
  for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
  {
    var fechild=VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(fe, i) as FrameworkElement;
    if (fechild != null)
      IterateXamlNullOutTag(fechild);
  }
}
```

Considering cleaning up your object in a similar fashion

Comment: You may also want to clear away bound data prior to exporting the xaml:
      if (fe is DependencyObject)
      {
        BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(fe as DependencyObject);
      }